# IE 8 does not want my download at the first time

Tags: internet-explorer, zend-framework2

I have a Zend Framework 2 application which provides a file download.
The download action looks like this

```
use Zend\Http;

[...]

public function sendDownload()
{
    $file = '/tmp/foo';
    if (!is_readable($file) || !is_file($file)) {
        throw new \Core\Mvc\Exception\NotFoundException(sprintf("File '%s' not found.", $file));
    }

    $baseName = 'foo.zip';

    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
    finfo_close($finfo);

    $response = new Http\Response\Stream();
    $response->setStream(fopen($file, 'r'));
    $response->setStatusCode(200);

    $headers = new Http\Headers();
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', $mimeType);
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="' . $baseName . '"');
    $headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', filesize($file));

    $response->setHeaders($headers);
    return $response;
}
```

When I open the download link in a fresh Internet Explorer 8 session the download fails.

[image: Screenshot]

"Text: xxxx can not be downloaded. The website is not available or could not be found. Try again later".

When I try to open the link a second time in the same session, everything works fine.

This is reproducible. I reopen IE - download - fails - again - works.

In other browsers it works.

When checking the action in XDebug, the steps performed are the same.
In the apache access log it both times shows code 200 - but a slightly different size.

Did anybody see such a behaviour before?

Comment: What I will check is if there are cookies involved ... that would explain why it is working in the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've seen this before, but can't remember exactly the cause. I think it was some combination of certain cache headers and possibly HTTPS?

Try adding:

```
$headers->addHeaderLine('Cache-Control', 'private, must-revalidate');
```

Also see if Content-Disposition inline works instead of attachment.